# How to set the array inside useState using react hook and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have problem putting the different list items from redux state to the UseState, I used useSelector of react-redux to get the state on my redux it happens when I console log the state, useSelector value has array of 0 but when I console log the selector there is a data.

Redux:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchBanks())
    dispatch(fetchRemarks())
    dispatch(fetchBankAccounts())
    dispatch(fetchCustomerPayor())
}, [fetchBanks,fetchRemarks,fetchBankAccounts,fetchCustomerPayor])



const list_bank =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_banks.data);
const list_remarks =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_remarks.data);
const list_bank_accounts =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_bank_accounts.data);
const list_customer_payor =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_customer_payor.data);
```

setState:

```
console.log(list_bank,"start");


const defaultArray = [
    {
        key:"0",
        customer:list_customer_payor,
        bank:list_bank,
        branch:"",
        checkNo:"",
        amount:"",
        remarks:list_remarks,
        checkDate:""
    },
    {
        key:"1",
        customer:list_customer_payor,
        bank:list_bank,
        branch:"",
        checkNo:"",
        amount:"",
        remarks:list_remarks,
        checkDate:""
    },
    {
        key:"2",
        customer:list_customer_payor,
        bank:list_bank,
        branch:"",
        checkNo:"",
        amount:"",
        remarks:list_remarks,
        checkDate:""
    },
    {
        key:"3",
        customer:list_customer_payor,
        bank:list_bank,
        branch:"",
        checkNo:"",
        amount:"",
        remarks:list_remarks,
        checkDate:""
    },
    {
        key:"4",
        customer:list_customer_payor,
        bank:list_bank,
        branch:"",
        checkNo:"",
        amount:"",
        remarks:list_remarks,
        checkDate:""
    }
];

console.log(defaultArray,"test");

const [data, setData] = useState(defaultArray) 

console.log(data,"end");
```

Output of state has no data:

[image: State]

Comment: What actions are dispatched and how do they change the state (redux devtool output and reducer code)? Are you trying to set local state with redux state that has not been set yet? Are you mutating state in the reducer?

Comment: What I am trying to explain is. I have already list of state on my redux (list_customer_payor, list_bank, list_remarks).  Now this list of state, I want to put it inside of my defaultArray. Now I already declared it on my objects (customer,banks,remarks,). Then this defaultArray I want to put it on my local state. The problem here when I try to console the local state data the list of datas that put on has no value.

Comment: wouldn't you need to use the spread operator in this instance?  ```const list_bank =  useSelector((state) => ...state, receive_checks.list_banks.data);```

Comment: Right now i found out. when I refresh the page the selector is removed. thats why the array is 0

Comment: initial solution I will go to the other page and I will back to that page the list is back. but the new question here how to set it permanently even I refresh the page

Comment: the next question: useselector not updating after I refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

> the next question: useselector not updating after I refresh the page

If you want your state to survive refresh, use some like [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist). It will preserve state in local storage.

As far as your intial question goes, you need to post more code.